# Cannot change long period for timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) while my program is running

Tags: java, netbeans, 2d-games, conways-game-of-life, jslider

I am making John Conway's game of life and I cannot figure out how to change the period or in this case the timelength in the `time.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, timelength)` in my code while the the program is running. I am trying to change the timelength using a jslider in my code but it does not change at all. In the code some of is creates the graphis which can be ignored and alot of the other code is for stuff such as jtextfields and jbutton.

```
//Game of Life
package ics_sad_majorproject.gameoflifejava_1;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GameOfLife extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    int intperiod = 100;
    int wid = 50, hei = 50;
    boolean[][] currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid], nextMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
    boolean play;
    public static int intpopulation = 0;
   Image offScrImg;
   Graphics offScrGraph;
  public static int intGeneration = 0;
  Timer time = new Timer();

   public GameOfLife() {
        initComponents();
        offScrImg = createImage(jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());
        offScrGraph = offScrImg.getGraphics();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
          public void run() {
              if(play == true){
                  intGeneration++;
               jLabel6.setText( "Generation: " + intGeneration );
              for(int i = 0; i < hei; i++){
                  for(int j = 0; j < wid; j++){
                      nextMove[i][j] = decide(i,j);
                  }   
                  }
               for(int i = 0; i < hei; i++){
                  for (int j = 0; j < wid; j++){
                  currentMove[i][j] = nextMove[i][j];
                  }   
                  }
               repain();
                  }
          }
            };
        time.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, intperiod);
        repain();
    }

private boolean decide(int i, int j){
    int neighbors = 0; 
    if(j > 0){
        if(currentMove[i][j-1]) neighbors++;
        if(i>0) if(currentMove[i-1][j-1]) neighbors++;
        if(i<hei-1) if(currentMove[i+1][j-1]) neighbors++;
    }
    if(j < wid - 1){
        if(currentMove[i][j+1]) neighbors++;
        if(i>0) if(currentMove[i-1][j+1]) neighbors++;
        if(i<hei-1) if(currentMove[i+1][j+1]) neighbors++;
    }
     if(i>0) if(currentMove[i-1][j]) neighbors++;
     if(i<hei-1) if(currentMove[i+1][j]) neighbors++;
     if(currentMove[i][j]&& neighbors < 2)intpopulation--;
     if(currentMove[i][j]&& neighbors > 3)intpopulation--;
     if(currentMove[i][j] && neighbors == 3)intpopulation--;
     if(neighbors == 3) intpopulation++;
  jLabel5.setText("Population: " + Integer.toString(intpopulation));
     if(neighbors == 3) return true;
     if(currentMove[i][j] && neighbors == 2)return true;
     return false;
     }

    private void repain(){
        offScrGraph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        offScrGraph.fillRect(0, 0, jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < hei; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < wid; j++){
                if(currentMove[i][j])
                {
                    offScrGraph.setColor(Color.getHSBColor((float) Math.random(), .8f, .8f));
                int x  = j * jPanel2.getWidth()/wid;
                int y = i * jPanel2.getHeight()/hei;
             offScrGraph.fillRect(x, y, jPanel2.getWidth()/wid, jPanel2.getHeight()/hei);
                 }
        }
        }
        offScrGraph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 1; i < hei; i++){
            int y = i * jPanel2.getHeight()/hei;
            offScrGraph.drawLine(0, y, jPanel2.getWidth(), y);
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < wid; j++){
            int x  = j * jPanel2.getWidth()/wid;
            offScrGraph.drawLine(x, 0, x, jPanel2.getHeight());
        }
         jPanel2.getGraphics().drawImage(offScrImg, 0, 0, jPanel2);
    }
 private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
         jLabel4.setText(Integer.toString(jSlider1.getValue()) + " milisecounds");
         intperiod = jSlider1.getValue(); 
    }      


private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
            intGeneration = 0;
            intpopulation = 0;
             jLabel6.setText( "Generation: " + intGeneration );
             jLabel5.setText( "population: " + intpopulation );
            repain();
        }                                        
         private void jPanel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
            int j = wid * evt.getX() / jPanel2.getWidth();
            int i = hei * evt.getY() / jPanel2.getHeight();
            currentMove[i][j] = true;
            intpopulation++;
            jLabel5.setText("Population: " + Integer.toString(intpopulation));
            repain();
        }                                    

        private void jPanel2ComponentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                         
            offScrImg = createImage(jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());
            offScrGraph = offScrImg.getGraphics();
            repain();
        }                                        

        private void jPanel2MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
            int j = wid * evt.getX() / jPanel2.getWidth();
            int i = hei * evt.getY() / jPanel2.getHeight();
            if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)){
            currentMove[i][j] = true;
            intpopulation++;
            }else currentMove[i][j] = false;
        }                                    

        private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            play = !play;
            if(play) jButton3.setText("Pause");
            else jButton3.setText("play");
            repain();
        }                                        

        private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
           String text = jTextField4.getText();
                hei = Integer.valueOf(text);
               jTextField4.setText("Height: "+ Integer.toString(hei));
                currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
                nextMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
                repain();
        }                                           

        private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
                String text = jTextField1.getText();
                wid = Integer.valueOf(text);
                jTextField1.setText( "Width: "+ Integer.toString(wid));
                currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
                nextMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
                repain();
        }             
    }
```

Comment: Hi David, referring to your question from the other post: Sure. Go ahead and post the other code, so I can have a look how to help you.

Comment: @DiabolicWords I posted it all

Comment: Hi David, I think I know what kind of errors you were facing yesterday. I corrected my code. Please copy the class back into your project and give it another try. In case of any other error, please add a comment to my solution and I'll try to get back to you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what follows is the entire GameOfLife.java.

Please copy and paste it 1:1 in your current file.

**Then recompile the project!** *(The 'Hammer with a broom'-button).*

If you now run your app, everything is supposed to run as you wanted. It runs perfectly and without any NPEs on my machine...

```
// code here is used to design the Jframe
package ics_sad_majorproject.gameoflifejava_1;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GameOfLife extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int intperiod = 100;
    int wid = 50, hei = 50;
    boolean[][] currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid], nextMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
    boolean play;
    public static int intpopulation = 0;
    Image offScrImg;
    Graphics offScrGraph;
    public static int intGeneration = 0;
    Timer time = new Timer();
    // DiabolicWords
    // make task globally reachable in order to be able to set it from everywhere
    TimerTask task;

    public GameOfLife() {
        initComponents();
        offScrImg = createImage(jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());
        offScrGraph = offScrImg.getGraphics();

        // DiabolicWords
        // start timer and task for the first time
        this.restartTimerTask();
        repain();
    }

    // DiabolicWords
    // put the (re)creation of the TimerTask in a separate method
    private void restartTimerTask() {
        // DiabolicWords
        // if a task already exists, cancel()
        if (task != null) {
            task.cancel();
        }

        // DiabolicWords
        // create a new task
        task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if (play == true) {
                    intGeneration++;
                    jLabel6.setText("Generation: " + intGeneration);
                    for (int i = 0; i < hei; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < wid; j++) {
                            nextMove[i][j] = decide(i, j);
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < hei; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < wid; j++) {
                            currentMove[i][j] = nextMove[i][j];
                        }
                    }
                    repain();
                }
            }
        };

        // DiabolicWords
        // run the new task
        time.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, intperiod);
    }

    private boolean decide(int i, int j) {
        int neighbors = 0;
        if (j > 0) {
            if (currentMove[i][j - 1]) {
                neighbors++;
            }
            if (i > 0) {
                if (currentMove[i - 1][j - 1]) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if (i < hei - 1) {
                if (currentMove[i + 1][j - 1]) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (j < wid - 1) {
            if (currentMove[i][j + 1]) {
                neighbors++;
            }
            if (i > 0) {
                if (currentMove[i - 1][j + 1]) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if (i < hei - 1) {
                if (currentMove[i + 1][j + 1]) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            if (currentMove[i - 1][j]) {
                neighbors++;
            }
        }
        if (i < hei - 1) {
            if (currentMove[i + 1][j]) {
                neighbors++;
            }
        }
        if (currentMove[i][j] && neighbors < 2) {
            intpopulation--;
        }
        if (currentMove[i][j] && neighbors > 3) {
            intpopulation--;
        }
        if (currentMove[i][j] && neighbors == 3) {
            intpopulation--;
        }
        if (neighbors == 3) {
            intpopulation++;
        }
        jLabel5.setText("Population: " + Integer.toString(intpopulation));
        if (neighbors == 3) {
            return true;
        }
        if (currentMove[i][j] && neighbors == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void repain() {
        offScrGraph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        offScrGraph.fillRect(0, 0, jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < hei; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < wid; j++) {
                if (currentMove[i][j]) {
                    offScrGraph.setColor(Color.getHSBColor((float) Math.random(), .8f, .8f));
                    int x = j * jPanel2.getWidth() / wid;
                    int y = i * jPanel2.getHeight() / hei;
                    offScrGraph.fillRect(x, y, jPanel2.getWidth() / wid, jPanel2.getHeight() / hei);
                }
            }
        }
        offScrGraph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 1; i < hei; i++) {
            int y = i * jPanel2.getHeight() / hei;
            offScrGraph.drawLine(0, y, jPanel2.getWidth(), y);
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < wid; j++) {
            int x = j * jPanel2.getWidth() / wid;
            offScrGraph.drawLine(x, 0, x, jPanel2.getHeight());
        }
        jPanel2.getGraphics().drawImage(offScrImg, 0, 0, jPanel2);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        jPanel2.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel2MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel2MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel2.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
                jPanel2ComponentResized(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 387, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jButton2.setText("Reset");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("play");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("Time Slider");

        jLabel3.setText("Grid: ");

        jTextField1.setText("width:50");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField4.setText("height: 50");
        jTextField4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jSlider1.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        jSlider1.setMaximum(500);
        jSlider1.setMinimum(1);
        jSlider1.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        jSlider1.setPaintTicks(true);
        jSlider1.setValue(3000);
        jSlider1.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                jSlider1StateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("100 milisecounds");

        jLabel5.setText("Population : 0");

        jLabel6.setText("Generation: 0");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(323, 323, 323)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 181, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(0, 294, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
        intGeneration = 0;
        intpopulation = 0;
        jLabel6.setText("Generation: " + intGeneration);
        jLabel5.setText("population: " + intpopulation);
        repain();
    }                                        

    private void jPanel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        int j = wid * evt.getX() / jPanel2.getWidth();
        int i = hei * evt.getY() / jPanel2.getHeight();
        currentMove[i][j] = true;
        intpopulation++;
        jLabel5.setText("Population: " + Integer.toString(intpopulation));
        repain();
    }                                    

    private void jPanel2ComponentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                         
        offScrImg = createImage(jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());
        offScrGraph = offScrImg.getGraphics();
        repain();
    }                                        

    private void jPanel2MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        int j = wid * evt.getX() / jPanel2.getWidth();
        int i = hei * evt.getY() / jPanel2.getHeight();
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) {
            currentMove[i][j] = true;
            intpopulation++;
        } else {
            currentMove[i][j] = false;
        }
    }                                    

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        play = !play;
        if (play) {
            jButton3.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            jButton3.setText("play");
        }
        repain();
    }                                        

    private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String text = jTextField4.getText();
        hei = Integer.valueOf(text);
        jTextField4.setText("Height: " + Integer.toString(hei));
        currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
        nextMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
        repain();
    }                                           

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String text = jTextField1.getText();
        wid = Integer.valueOf(text);
        jTextField1.setText("width: " + Integer.toString(wid));
        currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
        nextMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
        repain();
    }                                           

    private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
        jLabel4.setText(Integer.toString(jSlider1.getValue()) + " milisecounds");
        intperiod = jSlider1.getValue();

        // DiabolicWords
        // the intperiod was changed. Restart the timer and task.
        this.restartTimerTask();
    }                                     

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameOfLife.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameOfLife.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameOfLife.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameOfLife.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GameOfLife().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that a timer, once instantiated and started, doesn't check whether a parameter was changed, while it is running. It's kind of a closure.

You have to create a new timer instance with the new parameters, each time you change one of them.

> **EDIT**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class GameOfLife extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // Put this parameters global in order to be able to change it from different points in your code
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    int delay = 0;
    int period = 100;


    int wid = 200, hei = 100;
    boolean[][] currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid], nextMove = new boolean[hei]
            [wid];
    boolean play;
    public static int intpopulation = 0;
    Image offScrImg;
    Graphics offScrGraph;
    public static int intGeneration = 0;

    public GameOfLife() {
        initComponents();
        offScrImg = createImage(jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());
        offScrGraph = offScrImg.getGraphics();

        // start the very first timer instance
        restartTimer();

        repain();
    }

    /**
     * This method first checks, whether the timer is already instatiated.
     * If so, the current timer gets cancelled.
     * Then the timerTask gets recreated.
     *
     * Finally a new timer is instantiated and gets scheduled.
     */
    private void restartTimer() {
        if(timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }

        resetTimerTask();

        System.out.println("TimerTask: " + (timerTask != null));
        System.out.println("period: " + period);
        System.out.println("delay: " + delay);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, delay, period);
    }

    private void resetTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask(){
            public void run() {
                if(play == true){
                    intGeneration++;
                    for(int i = 0; i < hei; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < wid; j++){
                            nextMove[i][j] = decide(i,j);
                        }
                    }

                    for(int i = 0; i < hei; i++){
                        for (int j = 0; j < wid; j++){
                            currentMove[i][j] = nextMove[i][j];
                        }
                    }
                    repain();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt)      {
        jLabel4.setText(Integer.toString(jSlider1.getValue()));
        period = jSlider1.getValue();

        // whenever you change the period, start a new timer instance
        restartTimer();
    }

    private boolean decide(int i, int j){
        int neighbors = 0;
        if(j > 0){
            if(currentMove[i][j-1]) neighbors++;
            if(i>0) if(currentMove[i-1][j-1]) neighbors++;
            if(i<hei-1) if(currentMove[i+1][j-1]) neighbors++;
        }
        if(j < wid - 1){
            if(currentMove[i][j+1]) neighbors++;
            if(i>0) if(currentMove[i-1][j+1]) neighbors++;
            if(i<hei-1) if(currentMove[i+1][j+1]) neighbors++;
        }
        if(i>0) if(currentMove[i-1][j]) neighbors++;
        if(i<hei-1) if(currentMove[i+1][j]) neighbors++;
        if(currentMove[i][j]&& neighbors < 2)intpopulation--;
        if(currentMove[i][j]&& neighbors > 3)intpopulation--;
        if(currentMove[i][j] && neighbors == 3)intpopulation--;
        if(neighbors == 3) intpopulation++;
        jLabel5.setText("Population: " + Integer.toString(intpopulation));
        if(neighbors == 3) return true;
        if(currentMove[i][j] && neighbors == 2)return true;
        return false;
    }

    private void repain(){
        offScrGraph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        offScrGraph.fillRect(0, 0, jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < hei; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < wid; j++){
                if(currentMove[i][j])
                {
                    offScrGraph.setColor(Color.getHSBColor((float) Math.random(), .8f, .8f));
                    int x  = j * jPanel2.getWidth()/wid;
                    int y = i * jPanel2.getHeight()/hei;
                    offScrGraph.fillRect(x, y, jPanel2.getWidth()/wid, jPanel2.getHeight()/hei);
                }
            }
        }
        offScrGraph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 1; i < hei; i++){
            int y = i * jPanel2.getHeight()/hei;
            offScrGraph.drawLine(0, y, jPanel2.getWidth(), y);
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < wid; j++){
            int x  = j * jPanel2.getWidth()/wid;
            offScrGraph.drawLine(x, 0, x, jPanel2.getHeight());
        }
        jPanel2.getGraphics().drawImage(offScrImg, 0, 0, jPanel2);
    }

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
        intGeneration = 0;
        intpopulation = 0;
        jLabel6.setText( "Generation: " + intGeneration );
        jLabel5.setText( "population: " + intpopulation );
        repain();
    }
    private void jPanel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int j = wid * evt.getX() / jPanel2.getWidth();
        int i = hei * evt.getY() / jPanel2.getHeight();
        currentMove[i][j] = true;
        intpopulation++;
        jLabel5.setText("Population: " + Integer.toString(intpopulation));
        repain();
    }

    private void jPanel2ComponentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
        offScrImg = createImage(jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());
        offScrGraph = offScrImg.getGraphics();
        repain();
    }

    private void jPanel2MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int j = wid * evt.getX() / jPanel2.getWidth();
        int i = hei * evt.getY() / jPanel2.getHeight();
        if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)){
            currentMove[i][j] = true;
            intpopulation++;
        }else currentMove[i][j] = false;
    }

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        play = !play;
        if(play) jButton3.setText("Pause");
        else jButton3.setText("play");
        repain();
    }

    private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = jTextField4.getText();
        hei = Integer.valueOf(text);
        jTextField4.setText("Height: "+ Integer.toString(hei));
        currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
        nextMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
        repain();
    }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = jTextField1.getText();
        wid = Integer.valueOf(text);
        jTextField1.setText( "Width: "+ Integer.toString(wid));
        currentMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
        nextMove = new boolean[hei][wid];
        repain();
    }
}
```

Comment: (Tips: (a) if a question is replaced by a new one, you can do the same with corresponding answers i.e. the "edit" note is not needed. We primarily write for new readers here, and they can check the revision history if they really want to see an old version. (b) if you can, reserve quote block formatting for quotes.)

Comment: @DiabolicWords after copying your code it no longer displays the JFrame and it gives me these list of errors

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:399)
 at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Timer.java:328)
 at ics_sad_majorproject.gameoflifejava_1.GameOfLife.restartTimer(GameOfLife.java:38)
 at ics_sad_majorproject.gameoflifejava_1.GameOfLife.<init>(GameOfLife.java:28)
 at ics_sad_majorproject.gameoflifejava_1.ICS_SAD_MAJORPROJECTGAMEOFLIFEJAVA_1.main(ICS_SAD_MAJORPROJECTGAMEOFLIFEJAVA_1.java:4)

Comment: Okay, the system somehow claims that a NullPointer occurs on `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate();` I edited the code to get some more output. Please run it and post the result from the console.

Comment: @DiabolicWords this is the results:

Comment: TimerTask: false
period: 100
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
delay: 0                                                                                                    at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:399)
 at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Timer.java:328)
 at ics_sad_majorproject.gameoflifejava_1.GameOfLife.restartTimer(GameOfLife.java:44)
 at ics_sad_majorproject.gameoflifejava_1.GameOfLife.<init>(GameOfLife.java:29)
 at ics_sad_majorproject.gameoflifejava_1.ICS_SAD_MAJORPROJECTGAMEOFLIFEJAVA_1.main(ICS_SAD_MAJORPROJECTGAMEOFLIFEJAVA_1.java:4)

Comment: @DiabolicWords is it possible if I could send you my whole game file with all the code so you could run it on your computer and see the output so you could figure the problem out faster

Comment: Hi David, that would be okay with me. Do you have access to DropBox or other Cloud-Stores where you can put the code as a zip-file in?

Comment: @DiabolicWords Yes I just made a free account on Dropbox

Comment: Okay, then please put the code in there, preferably as a zip file, and put the link in the next comment here. I'll download your code and have a look on it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i0z5vr8k25ip3zx/AAAYTJ0cqFc0Sslfy_sC3Ccoa?dl=0

Comment: Okay, I've got the file and will have a look.

Comment: It should be under src @DiabolicWords